# Property shadowed by unenumerable property listed?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm wondering about the following.
Giving this Code:

```
function displayprops(obj, name) {
    console.log(name+":");
    for(var prop in obj)
        console.log(prop + ": " + obj[prop]);
}

var first = {prop: {}};
displayprops(first, "first"); // "prop: [object Object]"

var second = Object.create(first);
Object.defineProperty(second,"prop",{
     enumerable:false
});
displayprops(second, "second"); // "prop: undefined"
```

([Demo at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oqevam/4/edit))

All Objects created from `first` should Obviously onherit the
`prop` property.

But Why does an Object created from `second` still shows the `prop` in his properties when iterating over it, note that its value is `undefined`.

I expected when setting the enumerable descriptor to false, the Objects which inherit from this prototype, shouldn't show those properties any more

**Edit**:
When i extend Object.prototype (for whatever reason) with a method 
and setting the methods enumerable descriptor to false
it behaves as expected

Could someone explain this, maybe im thinkin in the wrong direction

Thx for the answers =)

Comment: On a note,  I would just like to state that given the name "proto" and the (bad) usage "__proto__" (assuming you were not mixing the two yourself) can cause a lot of confusion and I would suggest naming it something that is less confusing. Also, note that prototype is a method of a constructor (Object.prototype is a method of the function Object() which constructs new objects (using new Object() or simply {}) you create object based inheritence using only Object.create which creates an extension of an object.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What about [this much simpler code](http://jsbin.com/oqevam/4/edit), does it show the same behavior for you (or is my abstraction wrong)?

Comment: yes it shows the same behaviour (at least when using Chrome) 
i noticed this behaviour for the first time in titanium

Comment: OK, I've simplified your question a lot.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thx for noting this, the point is in my code i use it for example like this: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/upusik/1/edit) to have inheritance and private variables, and i just wrote it down on JSBin in a similar pattern, because i noticedc the behaviour in this, 
i didn't thought in this moment about an simpler example.

Comment: Err, do I have to accept the edit or is it applied automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the V8 JavaScript engine. I've come across it before. Enumerable properties in the prototype chain are included even if shadowed by a non-enumerable property.

There's already a bug report for it. <s>If I can find it again, I'll post it here.</s> Here it is...

[Issue 705: Non-enumerable property fails to shadow inherited enumerable property from for-in](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=705)

Test it in Firefox, and you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Thx =) that seems to be the problem,
umm now i just have to get titanium to use a other javascript engine^^

Comment: @Glutamat: Could you show us the usecase were you need this behavior? Just curious.

Comment: Sure I could host resources folder of an example along with some images of the compiled result on the iphone,  I'll do this on Monday I don't have time for it during the weekend I'm in a hurry right now

Comment: @Bergi  [TinyUpload](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08920746402883166312)

There you go, i just archived the js files and 2 images from an example, (table.js -> line 149 and 437 ) is where the Objects are set and enumerable is set to false (used with titanium and ios)